# Generating a list given the list length, an item, and filler items

Tags: haskell, polymorphism

First of all, sorry for the bad title, I really don't know what to call it. This is a question to one of my homework assignments:

"Write and test the definition of a (polymorphic) Haskell function `center` that takes 
three arguments:

1. a list `arg1` of type `[a]`,
2. a width `arg2` of type `Int`, and
3. a fill item `arg3` of type `a`,

and returns

a list of length `arg2` of type `[a]`,

containing the list `arg1` centered within fill items (i.e., the difference between the 
number of items preceding `arg1` and  those following `arg1` is at most 1).

For instance, `center "abcd" 7 '-'` could yield `"--abcd-"` or `"-abcd--"` (as you choose)."

I don't want you to actually code this function up for me since it's homework, but I just need some direction on how to solve this problem and perhaps a list of any Haskell functions that I may find useful in solving this problem.

Answer (score 3):

No recursion is necessary (on your part).  The result is going to consist of the input list sandwiched between left and right fill lists.  The `++` operator can concatenate lists:

```
center s w f = lfill ++ s ++ rfill where
  n = ... -- compute the total amount of fill required
  nl = ... -- divide the total fill into left  amount
  nr = ... -- divide the total fill into right amount
  lfill = ... -- replicate f nl times
  rfill = ... -- replicate f nr times
```

The `where` clause contains the code to create the left and right fill lists.

The total number of fill items (`n`) will be the difference between `w` and the length of `s`.  The number of fill items must be split between left (`nl`) and right (`nr`) by dividing by 2 and rounding either up (`ceiling`) or down (`floor`).  You could compute the left amount, and then compute the right amount by subtracting from the left amount from the total amount, or you could compute the left as the `floor` and the right as the `ceiling` of the division.  Once you have the left and right fill amounts, you can use `replicate` to create lists of the `f` item.

Answer (score 2):

## **Type Guidance**

### **Explicitly write down the type annotation**

You said (modulo few words),

> Write and test the definition of a (polymorphic) Haskell function center that takes three arguments:
>   arg1 of type [a], arg2 of type Int, arg3 of type a, returns a list of type [a]

Here I guess the first thing you should do is to write down the type signature of your function.
Writing explicitly the type annotation (signature) of the function is a very big guidance,

To help you, there is an example,

> If my function take two arguments:
>   arg1 of type Int, arg2 or type [a] and return a type a

I will write the following type annotation,

```
fun :: Int -> [a] -> a
```

Then your function, became,

```
center :: ... -> ... -> ... ->
```

### **Note, on your terminology**

There is some discrepancies between the definition of your function and the given example,

Considering this,

> return a list of length arg2 of type [a]

A list of type [a] sound for me, like a type [[a]], but you put this example,

> For instance, center "abcd" 7 '-' could yield "--abcd-" or "-abcd--" (as you choose)."

Do you see any type [[a]] ?
This is another good guidance try to correct this.

---

## **algorithmic, Guidance**

Now, let's take a look at the evil part, the algorithmic's one,

We have two main case to manage.

### **Bound case**

if the first argument is lesser or egal to the length of the list, then you can,
throw an exception **or** just retrieve the original list without any change. Anyway in both sub-case we shouldn't take care about the value of it third argument, should we ?

As an exercise, try to translate the previous sentence in Haskell.

Furthermore, What's it suppose to happen when the passed list is empty ?
Keep in mind, any no empty list can be express as (x:xs), with x = head list and xs = tail list.
Then most of time when you meet a function which deal with a list as input, you will have to manage these cases too.

May be center could look a bit like this,

```
center []     .. .. = ....  
center (x:xs) .. .. = ....
```

### **General case**

It's ok, bound case have been managed upper, we can be more focus on the functionality, if we refer to your example and we break it down in term of input.

```
"--abcd-" <=> ("--" ++ ("abcd" ++ "-"))
```

with, (++) being the concatenation operator,

```
"left," ++ "middle," ++ "right" => "left,middle,right"
```

Now, did you notice that following property's hold ?

```
(length "--") + (length "abcd") + (length "-") = 7
```

Any inspiration ?

The last tips,  try to evaluate following instruction into ghci,

```
replicate 2 '-'
```

Let's me know, if you still have another question, but the remaining arithmetic part seems quite straightforward, I mean, it doesn't rely on some Haskell knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

Using the width and divide it by half to find the median. You will have a special case of ending up with a non-integer median. This can be solved using the ceiling and floor functions. Then you could do something with the median... like the index of the fill.

Comment: The thing is, I'm not quite sure how to generate the `-'s` on the side of `abcd` as in the example. I'm also a bit confused with the prompt. If I am given a list of type [a], does that mean I have a list of lists?

Comment: Think of it as a queue, you put -'s until you hit the index of the letters and then fill it back up again with -'s. A list of type [a] just means a list of a type of data(i'm guessing [a] would be string or characters).

Comment: But how do I know whether each index is supposed a position of a letter or not? Sorry, I'm just really confused. Am I supposed to generate the `-'s` first then the `letters`, then more `-'s`? And what did you mean by "do something.. the index of the fill?"

Comment: Yes exactly how you described. Its a good idea to keep things simple. For example the case you described, you are given a list of abcd. Just output abcd to the list (you have to assume that the list of letters given aren't bigger then the size but you can check that with an if statement anyways).

Comment: As a ending note, you can find out when the letters end by using a counter.

Comment: Orginally, I was thinking to generate the amount of `-'s` equal to the length of the list minus the length of the word, and then stick the word in the middle. But your implementation seems less complicated. I'm still confused on how to generate this output. Normally in Java, I would have to run a for loop to generate the first two hyphens, then take the word from the list and concatenate it with the two hyphens I just made, and then generate the remaining hyphen and concatenate it with the concatenated word and hyphen. But this doesn't work in Haskell because I have to use recursion.

Answer (score -3):

You could need

replicate, 
length, 
floor, 
++

The skeleton of the function could be something like

replicate...++...++ replicate....

The ... must be filled with something.

Comment: -1: I think you could write this function with a couple of `foldl`s. The OP clearly needs a bit more guidance; this vague clue is not really helpful.